# Need something like ImageMap in GWT

Tags: gwt, imagemap

I need something like Html ImageMap & Html MapArea in my GWT project.
What is the best choice for me?

Is there any widget in standard GWT 2.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=gwt+imagemap) has a couple results, [this one](http://www.koders.com/java/fid1ACE81656C6F49C2E81126751E938A61215D6A6F.aspx?s=mdef:insert) in particular looks promising.

Comment: Where is the 'ImageMapImpl' definition in that example's link?

Comment: @Navid http://www.koders.com/java/fid14BAEF43A778EAC44CB31773D835279F59ADFF30.aspx?s=mdef:insert (linked in the sidebar)

Comment: Thanks, but how to use ImageMap class? how to bind to Image widget?